# How to properly insert and display data in an dynamically allocated arrays in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, data-structures, dynamic-arrays

I've been having trouble trying to properly display the correct memory address so I don't know in which memory address I'm inputting data.

```
    #include <iostream>
    
    using namespace std;

    int main() {

       system("cls");

       int *p = new int[2];

       for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
           cout << "Enter value for address " << p << ": ";
           cin >> p[i];
       }

       for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
           cout << *p << " " << p << endl;
           p++;
       }

    }
```

Here is the output when inputting data:

[image]

Here is the output when displaying them:

[image]

My concern is it doesn't output the correct memory address when inputting data.

[image]

But when displaying them it seems to have no problem displaying the correct memory address.

[image]

Comment: What do you do differently with `p` in the first loop compared to the second loop?

Comment: Discuss with [your Rubber Duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) what in the first loop changes the value of `p` such that you should expect a different address. Then discuss the code in the second for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input loop is displaying the `p` pointer as-is (ie, the base address of the array) on every iteration.  It is not adjusting the pointer on each iteration, unlike your output loop which does.

You are also leaking the array, as you are not `delete[]`'ing it when you are done using it.

Try this instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    system("cls");

    int *p = new int[2];

    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        cout << "Enter value for address " << &p[i] << ": ";
        cin >> p[i];
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        cout << p[i] << " " << &p[i] << endl;
    }

    delete[] p;
    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    system("cls");

    int *p = new int[2];

    int *elem = p;
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        cout << "Enter value for address " << elem << ": ";
        cin >> *elem;
        ++elem;
    }

    elem = p;
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        cout << *elem << " " << elem << endl;
        ++elem;
    }

    delete[] p;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note how Remy's code does not change the value of `p`. You cannot `delete` an allocation unless you know where it is. If you move where `p` points, you'd have to move it back before you can `delete[] p;`

Comment: Honestly, I don't even wanna talk about it haha thank you so much for this my mistake was already so obvious the whole time and I still didn't manage to see it.